# Modeless, parentless wxDialog still always above wxFrame window in z-order?

Tags: c++, gtk, wxwidgets, z-order

My program opens a wxFrame-based window and multiple modeless and parentless wxDialog-based windows. It all works beautifully, except that the wxDialog-based windows insist on always being on top of the wxFrame-based one.

I know about `wxDIALOG_NO_PARENT`, and I'm using it. The dialogs stay open when I close the wxFrame, so they definitely don't have the wxFrame window as a parent.

(If it matters, I'm using C++, wxWidgets 2.8.something, and running it on Ubuntu Linux. My program isn't ready to compile on any other platform, so I haven't tested it on others yet.)

I want *all* the windows to operate entirely independently, so the user can use the wxFrame window as well as the wxDialog ones. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This is a great question!!!  Using `wxDIALOG_NO_PARENT` actually solved my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that this behavior comes from a difference in how Gnome handles windows with different "type hints"...it puts them into their own z-index groupings:

https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html#GdkWindowTypeHint

The dialog is created with `GDK_WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_DIALOG` while your other window is most likely created with `GDK_WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_NORMAL`.  The point where this decision is made is in `gtk/toplevel.cpp` and it's being cued by the fact that the "extra" style flags contain `wxTOPLEVEL_EX_DIALOG`:

[toplevel.cpp#L594](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/2c69d27c0d225d3a331c773da466686153185320/src/gtk/toplevel.cpp#L594)

Those are the only two calls to `gtk_window_set_type_hint` in the wxWidgets GTK codebase, except for in the splash screen code.  So changing the "extra" style bits after the fact isn't going to help.  (The "correct" solution would be to patch wxWidgets so that adjusting `wxTOPLEVEL_EX_DIALOG` in the extra styles would do the proper adjustment to the window type hint.)

You can't use the wxDialog class without running through its constructor, which calls the non-virtual method `wxDialog::Create`, which sets the extra style to `wxTOPLEVEL_EX_DIALOG` and then goes directly to top level window creation:

[dialog.cpp#L54](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/2c69d27c0d225d3a331c773da466686153185320/src/gtk/dialog.cpp#L54)

So I guess you have the option of trying this, which works if you haven't shown the dialog window yet:

```
#ifdef __WXGTK__
gtk_window_set_type_hint(
    GTK_WINDOW(iShouldBeUsingQtDialog->GetHandle()),
    GDK_WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_NORMAL);
#endif
```

...and if you have shown the dialog already, you need to use this for it to work:

```
#ifdef __WXGTK__
gdk_window_set_type_hint(
    iShouldBeUsingQtDialog->GetHandle()->window,
    GDK_WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_NORMAL);
#endif
```

Both cases will require you to add an include file into your source:

```
#ifdef __WXGTK__
#include "gtk/gtkwindow.h"
#endif
```

...and you'll have to update your build to find the GTK includes.  On the command line for G++ I tried this and it worked:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0
```

Comment: Thanks. It was a valiant effort, but in vain: none of the windows has that option. :-(

Comment: Good Lord... I did *not* expect anyone to go to that level of effort for something this trivial. I'd mark this as accepted for the effort even if it didn't work, but I'm happy to report that it does -- you've nailed it. :-D Thank you!

Comment: That change also fixed another problem I had, where the modeless parentless dialogs would always appear in the center of the screen. I hadn't had a chance to look for the cause of that yet, now I don't have to. :-D Let me know if you're ever in the Toronto area, I owe you a beverage of your choice.

Comment: You're welcome (now just don't say the Interwebs never gave you anything...)  If you want to repay me, work through some Qt tutorials some night if you haven't already--then become a convert and help persuade people to deprecate wxWidgets and GTK!!  The license war has now been won, so no need to use 'em...

Comment: LOL on the "trivial". Not sure about Qt's preprocessor stuff, if I remember right, but I'll take another look at some point.

Comment: @DavidFraser Thanks for the link update, and hope this is useful for you.  But do note that if you don't want links to go further out of date, you need to include the commit hash.  Hitting "Y" when the page is open in GitHub will mutate the link to include the hash of the current commit.  See [GitHub permalinks](https://help.github.com/articles/getting-permanent-links-to-files/)